# Объясните структуру зачем в проекте использовать 2 манифеста?

Tags: android

Вот я уже не раз встречаю такие проекты в которых структура самого проекта делиться на 2-е... 2 файла манифеста 2 директории java и 2 директории res... Зачем это делают? и как в таком случае запускается проект? Я так понимаю, что программа читает структуру по манифесту? А когда их 2, как тогда она понимает структуру проекта?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такая структура нужна для распространения библиотеки и приложения-примера её использования.
Для использования библиотеки вам нужен только модуль `library`

Answer (score 3):

У вас в проекте открыта библиотека, модуль library, и пример к ней, модуль sample. Библиотека имеет [аналогичную структуру](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryModules) что и обычный [модуль приложения](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationModules). Т.е. у них есть свои папки `build/` `libs/` `src/` `AndroidManifest.xml`, которые они используют в работе. Они нужны для того, чтобы определить нужные им файлы исходного кода, ресурсы, разрешения, которые им необходимы и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Я тут покопался и если я правильно понял, то в данном случае таким образом в проект добавляют библиотеку.

Библиотека добавляется в существующий проект как отдельный проект и она имеет свой манифест и все сопутствующие ресурсы.

В процессе имплементации ее в мой проект мне потребовалось добавить строчку в `build.gradle` на уровне `module` в `dependencies`, вот такую строчку

```
compile project (':library')
```

, потом в `settings.gradle` добавил

```
include ':library', ':app'
```

и в `build.gradle` на уровне `Project` изменил свой `classpath` на

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
```

и все заработало))